# pass parameter to custom console command symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

In order to get the current user in console command, I want to pass the user_id to my custom console command.

1.Is there a way to implement this?

2.Or are there any other good ways to get the current user?

Thx

Comment: `current user` refers to what? the UNIX user? Or do you want to give an `id` and Symfony2 looks the user up in it's database?

Comment: You mean cli? Use the argv array

Comment: Not the Unix user. Just the user who sign in my page. @byf-ferdy

Comment: Could you please explain more in detail? Thank you very much @RoyalBg

Comment: The $argv array contains the parameters passed through the console. E.g.: `php path/to/file/file.php bla` $argv[1] will be 'bla'. So, for example, if you have `SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = $argv[1]` and you call `php path/to/file/file.php 100` you will endup in your script with `SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = 100`

Comment: Can only one user at a time log into your symfony2 app? What if multiple users are logged in?

Comment: Thank you I'll have a try. @RoyalBg

Comment: Thats a good question. I have to think it over. Thx @byf-ferdy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For selecting a certain user over the command line you can take a look at [the command](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Command/CreateUserCommand.php) of the famous `FOSUserBundle`:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $username = $input->getArgument('username');
    // interact with the username.
```

Call the command like `php app/console your:command username`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank to @RoyalBg very much. I solve the problem by adding a argument.

```
->addArgument('user_id', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'The id of the current user')
```

then I run the command

```
php app/console ssss $userid
```

it works.